# How to write Dynamic LINQ queries using DBContext in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, dbcontext, entity-sql

I am modifying my project to use DBContext instead of ObjectContext.
My existing code

```
var query = context.Vehicles.OrderBy("it.VehicleType.VehicleTypeID").
            GroupBy("it.VehicleType.VehicleTypeID", "Min(it.ODO_Reading) AS MinRunVehicle, it.VehicleType.VehicleTypeID");
```

The above code is written using ObjectContext.
After changing my project to inherit from DBContext I am getting the below error

```
    Error   89  The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Queryable.OrderBy<TSource,TKey>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource,TKey>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

I want to know how to specify dynamic Linq query in DBContext. Can somebody help.

Comment: You don't need dynamic queries, you can create a query using a fluent style  by successively applying LINQ functions, eg `q= q.Where(...); if (x){q=q.GroupBy(...).OrderBy(...);}`

Comment: Yes I can write queries using LINQ methods but I should not use LINQ methods as my project insists to use dynamic queries.

Comment: There's no such thing as dynamic LINQ queries. Are you confusing LINQ with [eSQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb399560(v=vs.100).aspx)? Your first example is *not LINQ*, it's eSQL

Comment: I want to write the above ESQL using [DBContext]. Earlier my class inherited from ObjectContext. ESQL supported in ObjectContext but i am not able to use DBContext for writing ESQL.

Comment: DbContext contains an ObjectContext. You can get to it with `((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext` ...

Comment: Yes, but I cannot get the entities using the object created using above syntax. For e.g., `objectContext = (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext; var customers = context.objectContext.Vehicles.... is not possible.`.I am not getting the **Vehicles** entity using above casting

Comment: I've already posted an answer that shows how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example uses eSQL, not some type of dynamic LINQ.

DbContext doesn't allow you to perform eSQL queries directly, but you can get access to the underlying ObjectContext and use it as before:

```
var query = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext
                                            .CreateQuery<Vehicle>("<ESQL Query>")
```

Comment: But if you see my query it includes ESQL in GroupBy and OrderBy..Is it possible to write these in ESQL?

Comment: I got it. I can give as below `var query1 = context.objectContext.CreateQuery<Employee>("TIME'23:59:59'").OrderBy(x => x.EmployeeName)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var query = context.Vehicles.OrderBy(m=>m.it.VehicleType.VehicleTypeID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to convert it all including `OrderBy` and `GroupBy`

```
void Main()
{

    var vehicles = new List<Vehicle>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        vehicles.Add(new Vehicle());
    }

    vehicles.OrderBy(vehicle     => vehicle.VehicleType.VehicleTypeID)
            .GroupBy(vehicleType => vehicleType.VehicleType.VehicleTypeID, 
                     vehicle     => vehicle.ODO_Reading, 
                                    (vehicleTypeID, minRunVehicle) => new 
                                    {
                                        VehicleTypeId = vehicleTypeID, 
                                        minRunVehicle = minRunVehicle
                                    })
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(vehicle => 
                     {
                         Console.WriteLine(vehicle.VehicleTypeId);
                         vehicle.minRunVehicle.ToList()
                                              .ForEach(minRun =>
                                              {
                                                  Console.WriteLine ("\t > :" + minRun);
                                              });
                         Console.WriteLine ("\n");
                     });
}

public class Vehicle
{
    public Vehicle()
    {
        this.VehicleType = new VehicleType();
        this.ODO_Reading = random.Next(100, 100000);
    }

    public VehicleType VehicleType { get; set;  }
    public int ODO_Reading { get; set; }
}

public class VehicleType
{
    public VehicleType()
    {
        VehicleTypeID = random.Next(1, 10);
    }

    public int VehicleTypeID { get; set; }
} 

public static Random random = new Random();
```

[image]

Comment: Where are you finding the Min value of ODO_Reading?